# How to Add values in checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Checkbox list where i can set the % of each process for a particular item
Here I am Having 3 process in a checkbox list
Packing 20%
Sanatising 10%
Stain 5% and Item with 10.00

so if i select multiple processes from the check box list
i need to get the total value of the item

my code is like this

```
if (cblTaskDetails.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected))
{

    for (int i = 0; i < cblTaskDetails.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cblTaskDetails.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in cblTaskDetails.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    string selectedValue = item.Value;
                    DataTable dt = tdbll.GetPercent(selectedValue);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        percent = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PricePercent"].ToString());
                        value = (percent * Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text)) / 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            txtRate.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(value + Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text))).ToString();

            txtAmount.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text)).ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing with this code? Did you try debugging the code to figure out what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Here I am getting correct calculation while selecting just one process from the check box list but while selecting mutiple more than 1 the calculation is becoming wrong

Comment: yes only for the selected values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (cblTaskDetails.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected))
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in cblTaskDetails.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        string selectedValue = item.Value;
                        DataTable dt = tdbll.GetPercent(selectedValue);
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            percent = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PricePercent"].ToString());
                            value += (percent * Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text)) / 100;
                        }
                    }
                }
                txtRate.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(value + Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text))).ToString();

                txtAmount.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text)).ToString();
            }
```